# how to mantain one current working directory for each window config in eyebrowse mode?

Tags: window, frames

I'm using eyebrowse-mode and I want to mantain a separte current-working directory for each eyebrowse-window-config.

I would like that window-config-1 had it's own current working directory, so that, for example, if I M-x find-file in slot-1 then dired starts at the directory tied to slot-1. if I M-x find-file in slot-2, then dired starts at the directory tied to slot-2. So on and so forth.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Author here. This is a serious impedance mismatch. Why would a set of windows dictate a buffer-local variable? Are you aware that a window config can display *any* buffer?

Comment: Did you consider writing a smarter replacement for `M-x find-file` that uses a different starting directory than of the buffer it happens to be in? See also https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile

Comment: @wasamasa, hi and thanks for the awesome package. Yes, I'm aware of that and my lisp knowledge is limited. The use case for this scenario is as follows: I want that when I run `M-x projectile-ag` in window-config-1, it always looks at the directory I've specified for window-config-1, in other words, I want that window-config-1's current working directory be the project root dir that I've defined for window-config-1. So on and so forth, so that each window-config is really a different project. Makes sense?